# How to integrate Rust UDF using C in Clickhouse?

Tags: c, rust, user-defined-functions, clickhouse

Have a UDF in C
main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *u_shaped_processor(char* camps_list_c);

void replacechar(char *s,char c1,char c2) {
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;s[i];i++) {
        if(s[i]==c1) {
            s[i]=c2;
        }
        if (s[i]=='\n'){
            s[i] = '\0';
        }

    }

}

void str_replace(
    char *target,
    const char *needle,
    const char *replacement
) {
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    char *insert_point = &buffer[0];
    const char *tmp = target;
    size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
    size_t repl_len = strlen(replacement);

    while (1) {
        const char *p = strstr(tmp, needle);

        // walked past last occurrence of needle; copy remaining part
        if (p == NULL) {
            strcpy(insert_point, tmp);
            break;
        }

        // copy part before needle
        memcpy(insert_point, tmp, p - tmp);
        insert_point += p - tmp;

        // copy replacement string
        memcpy(insert_point, replacement, repl_len);
        insert_point += repl_len;

        // adjust pointers, move on
        tmp = p + needle_len;
    }

    // write altered string back to target
    strcpy(target, buffer);
} 

int main(){
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int index = 0;
    int range = 0;
    line = (char*) malloc(len);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1){
        range = atoi(line);
        index = 0;
        while (index < range){
            line = (char*) malloc(len);
            read = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
            char *final_string = u_shaped_processor(line);
            str_replace(final_string, "\"", "\\\"");
            //replacechar(line, '"', "'");
            printf("{\"result\": \"%s\"} \n", final_string);
            ++index;
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        line = (char*) malloc(len);
        index = 0;
    }
    //fclose(fp);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

rust func (src/lib.rs)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::str;
use std::ffi::CString;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};


#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct InputFormat {
    ts_list: Vec<(String, String)>,
}

extern {
    fn str_c() -> *const c_char;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn u_shaped_processor(camps_list_c: *const c_char) ->  *const c_char {
    let mut camps_map: HashMap<String, f64> = HashMap::new();
    //convert c string to rust string
    let c_str = CStr::from_ptr(camps_list_c);
    let rust_str = c_str.to_str().expect("Bad encoding");
    let camps_list_str: String = rust_str.to_owned();

    let value: InputFormat = match serde_json::from_str(&camps_list_str) {
                Ok(value) => value,
                Err(why) => panic!("{:?}", why)
        };
    let camps = value.ts_list.len();
    if camps == 1 {
        let record = camps_map
            .entry((*value.ts_list[0].0).to_string())
            .or_insert(0.0);
        *record += 1.0;
    } else if camps == 2 {
        let record = camps_map
            .entry((*value.ts_list[0].0).to_string())
            .or_insert(0.0);
        *record += 0.5;
        let record = camps_map
            .entry((*value.ts_list[1].0).to_string())
            .or_insert(0.0);
        *record += 0.5;
    } else {
        let mid_weight = 0.2 / (camps - 2) as f64;
        for i in 0..camps {
            let entry = camps_map
                .entry((*value.ts_list[i].0).to_string())
                .or_insert(0.0);
            if i == 0 || i == camps - 1 {
                *entry += 0.4;
            } else {
                *entry += mid_weight;
            }
        }
    }
   let mut result = HashMap::new();
   result.insert(
        "result".to_string(), 
        serde_json::to_string(&camps_map).unwrap()
    );
   let mut final_map = HashMap::new();
   final_map.insert(
        "result".to_string(),
        serde_json::to_string(&result).unwrap()
    );
    let c_string = CString::new(&*final_map["result"]).expect("CString::new failed");
    return c_string.into_raw(); // Move ownership to C
}

/// # Safety
/// The ptr should be a valid pointer to the string allocated by rust
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn free_string(ptr: *const c_char) {
    // Take the ownership back to rust and drop the owner
    let _ = CString::from_raw(ptr as *mut _);
}
```

function.xml

```xml
<function>
    <type>executable_pool</type>
    <name>att_c</name>
    <execute_direct>1</execute_direct>
    <argument>
        <type>Array(Tuple(Nullable(String), Nullable(DateTime)))</type>
        <name>ts_list</name>
    </argument>
    <return_type>String</return_type>
    <return_name>result</return_name>
    <format>JSONEachRow</format>
    <send_chunk_header>1</send_chunk_header>
    <command>attribution_c</command>
</function>
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT att_c([tuple(CAST(number AS Nullable(String)), CAST(now() AS Nullable(DateTime))), tuple(CAST(number+1 AS Nullable(String)), CAST(now() AS Nullable(DateTime))), tuple(CAST(number+2 AS Nullable(String)), CAST(now() AS Nullable(DateTime))), tuple(CAST(number+5 AS Nullable(String)), CAST(now() AS Nullable(DateTime)))]) as att
FROM system.numbers LIMIT 10
```

Result on local run:

```
1
{"ts_list":[["c1","2023-04-21 00:00:00"],["c2","2023-04-22 00:00:00"],["c3","2023-04-23 00:00:00"],["c4","2023-04-24 00:00:00"],["c5","2023-04-25 00:00:00"]]}
{"result": "{\"c4\":\"0.06666666666666667\",\"c2\":\"0.06666666666666667\",\"c5\":\"0.4\",\"c3\":\"0.06666666666666667\",\"c1\":\"0.4\"}"}
```

The above is the result expected as well
But I got
Error on CH:

```
Code: 1. DB::Exception: Function 'att_c': wrong result, expected 10 row(s), actual 0: while executing 'FUNCTION att_c(array(tuple(CAST(number, 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 1), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 2), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 5), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)'))) :: 2) -> att_c(array(tuple(CAST(number, 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 1), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 2), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')), tuple(CAST(plus(number, 5), 'Nullable(String)'), CAST(now(), 'Nullable(DateTime)')))) String : 7'. (UNSUPPORTED_METHOD) (version 22.7.1.2484 (official build))
```

Problem is with external function. The code with external fn commented works just fine and returns everything needed.
Is there a way I can debug by printing lines in clickhouse. Where can I find these logs?

Comment: Don't use _clickhouse_, but it looks like your use of `getline()` is flawed. Can't see why you don't pass in the destination pointer set to `NULL`, use the returned pointer and then simply call `free()` before the next iteration... Regardless, you're replacing instances of `"` (one char) with `\"` (two chars) into a temp buffer, THEN pushing the lengthened string back into the original (smaller) buffer... This is likely going to spill out of the buffer that `getline()` allocated,,, Looks dangerous to me... ("Works sometimes.": the very definition of UB.)

Comment: Having seen your rust code, I repeat: `str_replace()` is replacing multiple instances of a single character with **two** characters. Presume the buffer sent from rust is 60 characters. If you replace 6 characters with 12, then copy back into the original buffer, there's an overrun: 60 - 6 + 12 = 66 characters. You get UB when you don't respect boundaries. (Likely the same for your "test harness" using `getline()`...)

Comment: No that isnt the case.. getline reads from clickhouse and not what the function returns. Function returns a string ptr. which is being initialized at the time of calling the fn. For some reason when I compiled the same with gcc it worked but when I compiled with cmake it didnt.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes removing str replace also helped. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't read rust, but I see the last line of the rust function is `let c_string = CString::new( ...` From my brush with C++, this is creating a buffer that will be sized to accommodate only what's needed... Stuffing extra characters into that fixed sized buffer afterward will cause buffer overrun leading to UB... From here on, you're the expert. I don't know how these pieces fit together in _clickhouse_.

Comment: @Fe2O3 agreed. I commented out the str replace thing and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

My UDF worked for the above code when removed str replace in C and compiling using gcc.

These articles are good starting point

**Integrating rust and C**

https://medium.com/@AlexanderObregon/integrating-rust-into-existing-c-c-projects-e0810dbddded

**Sending data between the two langs**

https://dev.to/kgrech/7-ways-to-pass-a-string-between-rust-and-c-4ieb

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34946586)

Comment: My code worked. Just added this for FYI for others to refer.

Comment: Also please remove the delete votes as there isnt much documentation around integrating rust funcs using clickhouse. I feel this is going to be very useful for others.

Comment: You may want to consider rewriting your answer so it looks more like an answer and not a continuation of your question. Specifically explain how it addresses your original  question.